# How to read a specific line in a file?

Tags: python, file, printing

I'm having trouble with this code. It seems like a simple thing, but for some reason no matter what I do it doesn't work.

I'm trying to read a specific line from a file and if that line is empty it prints an error.
The problem is that the code doesn't work and keeps returning the same line even if there is something on that line.

To be more specific of what this should do the file has only one line at the begining.
"List".

After that everything else is empty. If I print what's in the file it returns
'List \n'.

So, I'm trying to check if the second line (index 1) is blank and then print the error
I tried doing this with a variable `lines = [1]`, but that didn't work.
Here is the link to what I tried to do with `lines = [1]`
https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-read-specific-lines-of-a-text-file-in-python

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line == "List: \n" + "\n":
            print("\nThere are no lists!")
        else:
            #Do something
```

Comment: What were you expecting `lines = [1]` to do? I'm not sure what you're asking…

Comment: @martineau Maybe they meant `something = lines[1]`, that's all I can figure.

Comment: @Random: We can only guess — the OP needs to clarify. Note there's already a variable named `lines` in the current code, so I would assume it's referring to that. Wait…Maybe they want `lines = [lines[0]]` which would change the variable into a list containing one item, the first line in the file.

Comment: I tried to do something similar to this code from the page I posted.

Comment: Joe, please don't post links to offsite code — put it into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before `if line == "List: \n" + "\n"` you could `print(repr(line))` and see that it is not the value you are looking for. `lines` is a list of lines and will have at most a single newline character and its at the end of the line. The final line may not have a newline depending whether the file terminates with one.

Instead, just look for the contents of a single line. Stripping the line deals with the newline and any inconvenient whitespace on the end and makes up for small mistakes in the file.

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    if not lines or lines[0].strip() != "List:":
        print("Invalid file")
    elif len(lines) < 2 or not(lines[1].strip()):
        print("\nThere are no lists!")
```

You don't need to read the entire file to do this. `zip` combines two collections, stopping at the shortest. leveraging that you could

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for _, line in zip(range(2), f)]
    if not lines or lines[0] != "List:":
        print("Invalid file")
    elif len(lines) < 2 or not(lines[1].strip()):
        print("\nThere are no lists!")
```

Comment: I'm trying to read the second line (index 1). "List" will always be in the file, so I want to see if the file has something or is blank in line 2.

Answer (score 1):

Since your line starts with the term "List", you can try

```
   with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
           lines = f.readlines()
           for line in lines:
               if line.startswith("List"):
                  # Do smth
               else:
                  #empty lines
```

Update :

Alternatively you can use

```
        if line and line.isspace():
            #empty
        else :
            #Not empty
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I want to read the second line if it is blank or not. Before this chunk of code I ask the user to insert lines of strings. So, in the case where there is a line at index 1 (below "List") then the code proceeds to the else statement.

Comment: @Joe In that scenario this  should work  if line and line.isspace(): #Not empty else : #empty

Comment: However, the file will always starts with "List", so it won't work. It will always stay at if.startwith and not move to else (if the second line is blank). Sorry, I'm still learning Python.

Comment: @Joe check the alternative code. It should work fine

Comment: This only returns what's inside of else.

Comment: @Joe It will move. Else part will only be reached if there is some sort of data in line other than spaces or empty strings

Comment: I understand, but what I meant is that it doesn't matter if the second line is blank or not. It keeps returning what's inside of the else statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226841/discussion-between-sahil-angra-and-joe).

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo():
    file = open('file.txt', 'r')
    content = file.readlines()
    j = 'List' #or word you are looking for
    for i in range(len(content)):
    if i == 5 and j not in content[i]: # 5 - the 5th line in the txt
        return False # or do smth
    else:
        return True # or do smth
```